# adding withCredentials:true, and responseType option to request.post python

Tags: python, python-requests

How do I do this (Add withCredentials: true, and responseType : 'arraybuffer' to request.post in python) ?

Essentially, I want to simulate this ajax post request:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : POST,
    withCredentials : true,
    responseType : 'arraybuffer',
  })
```

I'm assuming basic authentication

Comment: Please tell us at least: 1. what you are trying to do 2. which authentication type are you using

Comment: Essentially, I want to simulate this ajax post request:
  $.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : POST,
    withCredentials : true,
    responseType : 'arraybuffer',
  })
I'm assuming basic authentication